# Can't both, subscribe to update and set value manually in ionic ion-range

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just started my first ionic app project.

In my `player.component.html` I got that `<ion-range>`-element:

```html
<ion-range min="0" color="light" [max]="state?.duration" [formControl]="seekbar"
             [value]="state?.currentTime" (ionFocus)="onSeekStart($event)" (ionChange)="onSeekEnd($event)"
             name="seekbar">
</ion-range>
```

and my `player.component.ts` looks like this:

```js
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  files: any = [];
  seekbar: FormControl = new FormControl('seekbar');
  state: StreamState | null = null;
  onSeekState: boolean;
  currentFile: any = {};

  constructor(
    public audioProvider: AudioService,
    public cloudProvider: CloudService,
    public auth: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    
    this.audioProvider.getState().subscribe(s => {
      this.state = s;
    });
  } 

    onSeekEnd(event) {
        const val = event.detail.value;

      if (this.onSeekState) {
        this.audioProvider.seekTo(val);
        this.play();
      } else {
        this.audioProvider.seekTo(val);
      }

      this.seeking = false;
    }
```

so the state of `audioProvider` is subscribed and the `ion-range`s values gets updated.

Now I want to implement, when I click somewhere on the range, the current value needs to get changed. Possible actions are `(ionChange)` and `(ionBlur)` - both are fired when click on the range.

my problem is, I cant't use `ionChange` nor `ionBlur`:

- `(ionChange)` is always fired when the value changes. and the value changes always when `audioProvider` is playing.
- `(ionBlur)` doesn't provide the value. I can't get the value of that event and set it.

any idea what I could do?

Comment: try it with `ngModel` i think updating ng model will not trigger ionChange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it finally worked with `event.target.value` on `onBlur()`

```js
onSeekEnd(event) {
  const val = event.target.value;

  if (this.onSeekState) {
    this.audioProvider.seekTo(val);
    this.play();
  } else {
    this.audioProvider.seekTo(val);
  }

  this.seeking = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[value]` you can use `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<ion-range min="0" [max]="state?.duration" color="light" name="seekbar"
    [formControl]="seekbar"
    [(ngModel)]="state?.currentTime"
    (ionFocus)="onSeekStart($event)"
    (ionChange)="onSeekEnd()">
</ion-range>
```

And your `onSeekEnd` will looks:

```
onSeekEnd() {
    const val = this.state.currentTime;

    if (this.onSeekState) {
        this.audioProvider.seekTo(val);
        this.play();
    } else {
        this.audioProvider.seekTo(val);
    }

    this.seeking = false;
}
```